# Kentico 13 .NET Core MVC Routing Patters

Tags: kentico, kentico-13

I have the following code in my Startup.cs

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
                );
```

Routing doesn't work for the following method in the controller and returns 404

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int id)
{
}
```

The url I'm trying to navigate is

```
/home/our-villages/property/100
```

However, it's working fine without the parameter value '100'. It hits the controller action in this case.

```
/home/our-villages/property
```

I believe I'm missing something in reagards to setting up the routing with parameters here. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the id parameter for the method optional?

Try doing this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int id = 0)
{
}
```

or

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? id)
{
}
```